# Matlab terminate while compile caffe. Disabled - No sandbox or build area path

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-16.04, caffe

```
E0302 03:12:50.399718 23466 net.cpp:785]     [Backward] All net params (data, diff): L1 norm = (13513.7, 65688.6); L2 norm = (23.9842, 295.159)
F0302 03:14:40.549015 23466 syncedmem.hpp:31] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (29 vs. 0)  driver shutting down
*** Check failure stack trace: ***

------------------------------------------------------------------------
              abort() detected at Fri Mar  2 03:14:40 2018
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Current Visual      : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  Deployed            : false
  GNU C Library       : 2.23 stable
  Host Name           : lly
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Entitlement ID: 6257193
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b
  MATLAB Version      : 9.1.0.441655 (R2016b)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Linux 4.13.0-36-generic #40~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 23:25:58 UTC 2018 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (11905000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
abort()

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007fb35b643420
  RCX = 00007fb4b71e9428  RDX = 0000000000000006
  RSP = 00007fb49a94d008  RBP = 00007fb49a94d2e0
  RSI = 0000000000005baa  RDI = 0000000000005b76

   R8 = 0000000000000081   R9 = 00007fb35b643440
  R10 = 0000000000000008  R11 = 0000000000000202
  R12 = 00007fb35b643480  R13 = 0000000000000072
  R14 = 00007fb35b643420  R15 = 00007fb35b64ade0

  RIP = 00007fb4b71e9428  EFL = 0000000000000202

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007fb4b71e9428                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+00218152 gsignal+00000056
[  1] 0x00007fb4b71eb02a                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+00225322 abort+00000362
[  2] 0x00007fb35b42ee49             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so.0+00040521
[  3] 0x00007fb35b4305cd             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so.0+00046541
[  4] 0x00007fb35b432433             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so.0+00054323 _ZN6google10LogMessage9SendToLogEv+00000643
[  5] 0x00007fb35b43015b             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so.0+00045403 _ZN6google10LogMessage5FlushEv+00000187
[  6] 0x00007fb35b432e1e             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so.0+00056862 _ZN6google15LogMessageFatalD2Ev+00000014
[  7] 0x00007fb35b9fe8d0 /home/lly/work/caffe-ssd/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+01329360
[  8] 0x00007fb35b9c9512 /home/lly/work/caffe-ssd/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+01111314
[  9] 0x00007fb35b99bfca /home/lly/work/caffe-ssd/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+00925642
[ 10] 0x00007fb35b99c3dd /home/lly/work/caffe-ssd/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+00926685
[ 11] 0x00007fb35bbabae5 /home/lly/work/caffe-ssd/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+03087077
[ 12] 0x00007fb35b91a01f /home/lly/work/caffe-ssd/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+00393247
[ 13] 0x00007fb35b91a19a /home/lly/work/caffe-ssd/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64+00393626
[ 14] 0x00007fb4b71edff8                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+00237560
[ 15] 0x00007fb4b71ee045                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+00237637
[ 16] 0x00007fb4a6f047c0   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00767936
[ 17] 0x00007fb4a6f03011   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00761873
[ 18] 0x00007fb4a6bb9cfe /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00437502
[ 19] 0x00007fb4a6ba0878 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00333944 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000616
[ 20] 0x00007fb499146a38 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos_impl.so+02771512
[ 21] 0x00007fb4a6bf5bd5 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00682965
[ 22] 0x00007fb4a6bb9cfe /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00437502
[ 23] 0x00007fb4a6ba0878 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00333944 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000616
[ 24] 0x00007fb4a3b2a9b4 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+12614068
[ 25] 0x00007fb4a3b2aa50 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+12614224
[ 26] 0x00007fb4a3909306 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10380038
[ 27] 0x00007fb4a3909785 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10381189
[ 28] 0x00007fb4a3989cc8 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10906824
[ 29] 0x00007fb4a398ba2a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10914346
[ 30] 0x00007fb4a632aee0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02445024 _Z44inCallFcnWithTrapInDesiredWSAndPublishEventsiPP11mxArray_tagiS1_PKcbP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000080
[ 31] 0x00007fb4a766a77a   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00690042 _ZN3iqm15BaseFEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000522
[ 32] 0x00007fb4803cea3f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+00862783 _ZN9nativejmi14JmiFEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000319
[ 33] 0x00007fb4803f1bd5 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+01006549 _ZN3mcr3mvm27McrSwappingIqmPluginAdapterIN9nativejmi14JmiFEvalPluginEE7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000741
[ 34] 0x00007fb4a7660a0a   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00649738
[ 35] 0x00007fb4a764ceb2   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00569010
[ 36] 0x00007fb4a5ea805a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00159834
[ 37] 0x00007fb4a5ea8617 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00161303
[ 38] 0x00007fb4a5eaf519 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00189721
[ 39] 0x00007fb4a5eaf614 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00189972
[ 40] 0x00007fb4a5eaffa9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00192425 _Z8mnParserv+00000617
[ 41] 0x00007fb4a6ecc243   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00537155
[ 42] 0x00007fb4a6ece1ce   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00545230
[ 43] 0x00007fb4a6ece849   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00546889 _ZN5boost6detail17task_shared_stateINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIS6_EEEEEEvE6do_runEv+00000025
[ 44] 0x00007fb4a6ecd236   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00541238
[ 45] 0x00007fb4a7694b49   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00863049
[ 46] 0x00007fb4a768151c   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00783644 _ZN5boost6detail8function21function_obj_invoker0ISt8functionIFNS_3anyEvEES4_E6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferE+00000028
[ 47] 0x00007fb4a76811fc   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00782844 _ZN3iqm18PackagedTaskPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000428
[ 48] 0x00007fb4a7660a0a   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00649738
[ 49] 0x00007fb4a764c690   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00566928
[ 50] 0x00007fb4a764f048   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00577608
[ 51] 0x00007fb4b895340a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+02634762
[ 52] 0x00007fb4b89549af /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+02640303
[ 53] 0x00007fb4b89550e6 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+02642150 _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00000102
[ 54] 0x00007fb4a6ecc8c6   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00538822
[ 55] 0x00007fb4a6eccc42   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00539714
[ 56] 0x00007fb4a6eba8d6   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00465110
[ 57] 0x00007fb4b75856ba              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00030394
[ 58] 0x00007fb4b72bb41d                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01078301 clone+00000109
[ 59] 0x0000000000000000                                   <unknown-module>+00000000


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.** This crash report has been saved to disk as /home/lly/matlab_crash_dump.23414-1 **



MATLAB is exiting because of fatal error
Killed
```

Here is my hardware information:
ubuntu 16.04
gtx1070 
cdua8.0 
cudnn5.1 
NVIDIA Drivers: NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.111.run 
MATLAB2016b

> Any idea on how to solve this? Thank you very much!

---

**Here is my compile caffe process:** 
Because MATLAB library files and Ubuntu system library files conflict, first i backuped the MATLAB file, and then added the system files to the environment variables, so that the system will use the system's default dynamic file.

①Rename `libstdc++.so.6` to `libstdc++.so.6_back` in the directory of `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64` 
②execute `sudo make matcaffe -j8` which is successful. 
③execute `sudo make mattest -j8` get this wrong information:

```
Invalid MEX-file
'/home/lly/work/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64':
/home/lly/work/caffe/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64: undefined
symbol:
_ZN2cv8imencodeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_11_InputArrayERSt6vectorIhSaIhEERKSB_IiSaIiEE.

Error in caffe.set_mode_cpu (line 5)
caffe_('set_mode_cpu');

Error in caffe.run_tests (line 6)
caffe.set_mode_cpu();
```

④Then, I deleted six MATLAB files in directory `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64`, in order to solve this problem.But finally got the matlab crash problem.

```
sudo mv libopencv_core.so.2.4 libopencv_core.so.2.4.bak
sudo mv libopencv_core.so.2.4.9 libopencv_core.so.2.4.9.bak

sudo mv libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.bak
sudo mv libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9 libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9.bak

sudo mv libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.bak
sudo mv libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.9 libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.9.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following two things in your log.

```
Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
OpenGL                 : hardware
```

The first one needs to be populated by your graphics card driver information. That is not happening.

Perform the following test:

1. Put OpenGL to be Software. Check that it has been moved to software
   by typing:

   ```
    h = opengl('info')
   ```
2. Check that the current graphics driver field is populated with whatever software driver you have.
3. **Make sure to save these settings.**
4. Restart the Matlab.
5. Reconfirm the settings and make sure opengl is to software.
6. Replicate the crash.
7. Share the Log.

After this you can try running the memory diagnostic on your System Memory and Graphics Card.

I had faced a similar issue and it turned out that there was a problem in my System Memory and Graphics card.

But that you will come to know after the log report is generated.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is really because of NVIDIA driver's reason. Because I Installed NVIDIA driver  executed `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.111.run  --no-opengl-files`, which was not installed OpenGL file, and then caused MATLAB error. Now I reinstalled the graphics driver used `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.111.run`  which solved the problem, thank you very much!